# Command to move line up or down in Atom Editor

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor

I have used Sublime for years and am trying out Atom for the first time.

How can I move a single line or selected block up or down by one line? In sublime I could do this with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>, but that doesn't seem to work in Atom. Any ideas?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

In Atom you can just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>.

You can find these options on Atom menu : Edit > Lines > Move Line Up

Comment: I keep a list of frequently used Atom shortcuts here: https://github.com/nwinkler/atom-keyboard-shortcuts It contains this one and many others...

Comment: This doesn't work for several lines (I mean, with several cursor instances), as it does in Sublime :/ Anyone knows how to achieve this in Atom?

Comment: Should note that it is the Up *Arrow*, not Page Up.

Comment: Does not work for Mac OS, the better answer is the one from @dlcchang.

Answer (score 46):

**Windows:** `Ctrl+Up/Down`

**Mac:** `Ctrl+Cmd+Up/Down`

Don't have enough Rep to leave as a comment. But for @DanielM question.

**To move several lines in Atom:**

Select all the several lines you want move by mouse or by holding `shift` and moving up or down the lines you want, and then use either the commands for Windows `Ctrl+Up/Down` or Mac `Ctrl+Cmd+Up/Down`

**Note:** The whole line does not have to be selected as long as part of it is, it will move with the commands.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem, I solved editing keymap file and adding this:

```
'atom-workspace atom-text-editor':
  'alt-up': 'editor:move-line-up'
  'alt-down': 'editor:move-line-down'
```

So to move I use "**alt+up**" or "**alt+down**".

Comment: Change `atom-text-editor` to `atom-text-editor:not([mini])` to match the builtin bindings

Answer (score 4):

```
'.editor':
  'alt-up': 'editor:move-line-up'
  'alt-down': 'editor:move-line-down'
```

Answer (score 3):

Depends on your OS:

```
Linux & Windows: Ctrl + Up/Down
Mac: Ctrl + Cmd + Up/Down
```